# PHP loaded in subdirectory has significantly slower TTFB than in root

Tags: mysql, php, iis, azure, azure-web-apps

I have two identical Azure web app services (IIS) running PHP 7.3, 32bit.

On `webservice1.com`, I have installed Wordpress on the root. This has a TTFB of **225.24ms**.

On `webservice2.com`, I have copied all the Wordpress files from the `webservice1.com` root into `webservice2.com/blog`. I now have a TTFB of **7.88 seconds**. This issue occurs for every PHP page load on webservice2.com/blog. `webservice2.com` has a range of static content in the root and other subdirectories.

Why could this be? Both are referencing the same Azure Database for mySQL server, MySQL version 5.7.

I'm working this out as I go along so I do not have a lot of experience in server operations. I'd appreciate any insight, as I've been looking into this for a day or so already.

*Note: I'm aware of the configuration steps for moving Wordpress sites between domains and the database changes needed - I am not asking about that process. This issue persists even when I make those changes.*

Thanks!

Comment: Are WP and MySQL on different servers?  In the same "availability zone"?  If not, state where.

Comment: @RickJames Yes, they are on different servers but both in the same zone